# Automated traversal of documents in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have some complex documents stored in Mongo. I would like to get a summary of of the values stored at all the levels that I have in my collection. So for example I want to build stats on the collection. A typical document may look like:

```
{"field": {"nestedfield": value}, "field2": {"nestedfield": value1}}
```

So the idea is that if my documents look like this, I could auto transform to a list that has for `[value, value, value]` corresponding to "`field"`, `"nestedfield"` and `[value1, value1, value1]` for `"field2", "nestedfield"`.

The issue is there are so many top level keys and the nesting could be arbitrary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way easily in Mongo Itself, so I decided to do this at the document level, i.e. at the dictionary level. I wrote the following recursive routine for expand the data-structure and flatten:

```
def extract(parent, key_str, storage):

    if not isinstance(parent, list) and not isinstance(parent, dict): # value
        storage[key_str] = parent
    elif isinstance(parent, dict):
        for k in parent.keys():  # dict
            print k
            extract(parent[k], key_str+"_"+str(k), storage)
    elif isinstance(parent, list):
        for i, j in enumerate(parent): # list
            print i, j
            extract(j, key_str+"_"+str(i), storage)
```

so it would be called as the following:

```
for a in db.collection.find():
        storage = {}
        extract(a, "head", storage)
```